# 0_ os_lock_corruption_abort in NSURLProtocol

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlprotocol

I've built a custom NSURLProtocol which is used by a WebView whilst it browses. But at seemingly random times (between a 20 seconds or a few minutes into browsing) I am getting an `EXC_BREAKPOINT` and the app stops running in my NSURLProtocol.

The relevant part of my NSURLProtocol is below, it's the last line which is showing the `EXC_BREAKPOINT`

```
self.mutableData = NSMutableData(data: data!)  
self.response = response  
self.client?.URLProtocol(self, didReceiveResponse: response!, cacheStoragePolicy: NSURLCacheStoragePolicy.Allowed)  
self.client?.URLProtocol(self, didLoadData: data!)  
self.client?.URLProtocolDidFinishLoading(self)
```

The Xcode error is visible below:
[image]

I'm totally bamboozled on this one. Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this, and how to fix it?

Thank you!

Sam

Comment: Getting the same crash in production, although I don't think we ever saw this locally. Puzzled by this as well.

Comment: @Sam Heather did you manage to find the solution for this. I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @Gyanendra still no solution, I'm sorry to say

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough context for me to fully understand the code here, much less guess what's wrong, but basically what's happening is that there's a lock (mutex) that has been deallocated, but is still being used somewhere down in the NSURL* stack.

This probably points to something not getting retained properly, but it is anybody's guess what or where.  It might even be that your protocol is not getting retained properly, in which case you might be able to fix it by assigning your protocol object to a property on itself until after you call your last delegate method, then nulling it out.

With that said, there's reason to believe that this is a bug in the OS itself, so while you try to work around it, you should also file a bug.  It will get duped to the other dozen or so bugs from other people who have asked this same question both here and on the Apple developer forums.  :-)